# Laravel asset vs mix

Tags: laravel, include, assets

I don't get to understand the difference between using `asset` or `mix` Laravel helper when you have to include some `js` or `css` file.

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

**vs**

```
<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Both generates a link to `public` folder so is there any difference between them? Is it better to use one of them instead of the other? In which context is it better?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`asset` is just a helper to get the correct path to the file you are using as parameter, where `mix` also includes a version number, to help prevent caching of assets.

[Read this page to understand more about mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix).

Comment: do note that if `mix-manifest.json` is not present that `mix` will thrown an exception*

Comment: So which one should I use to just include a `js` or `css` file? Or maybe doesn't matter?

Comment: @Alberto If you're using versioning in your mix file, use `mix`. If you don't know what I'm talking about or aren't using versioning for your assets, use `asset`

Comment: i have project in dev stage, and i still use localhost/project/public folder, asset works well, but mix tries to get assets from localhost/css/styles.css. How do I configure, that mix method will work same as asset?

Comment: @Aleksandrs do you mean your gulp file or the url that is generated? Because `mix` and `asset` should return the same url, but `mix` includes a version parameter