# What's the difference on using `mix` and `asset` when including js file in routing?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes, vue-router

A minor question. I was trying to learn routing using Vue.JS in laravel, so I went to this [website](https://laravel-news.com/using-vue-router-laravel) and I see :

`<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>`

And this differs from what I know on including `app.js` into my website like this:

`<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>`

My question is:

1. Is there any difference on using one of them?
2. When to use `mix` or `asset`?
3. Does using `asset` affect routing in Vue.JS?

I tried using either of them, but as I said, I'm new to routing using laravel & Vue.JS so I don't know where I did wrong. I can't get it to work.

I've also tried googling, but what they show isn't related to my question,

.

.

PS: Additional Notes.

1. In my "website" I already implemented Authentication. Could be a factor *or not* that cause my routing to fail. If so, how to handle this?

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50926914/laravel-asset-vs-mix), and for more information about mix please visit this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel asset vs mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50926914/laravel-asset-vs-mix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mix()` function will bring you the versioned file of that asset(with a unique id) While the `asset` function  will not take into affect changes made to that asset while running `npm run dev or npm run watch` The mix function is for cache busting.